# C# how to capture stored procedure exceptions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

Code:

```
using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        var recibir = reader.VisibleFieldCount;
        var rear = reader;

        response.Add(new Cuota
            {
                opcion = (int)reader["PC_NUMERO_OPCION"],
                cuota = (int)reader["PC_NUMERO_CUOTAS"]
            });
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the exceptions of SQL Server, what are the corresponding methods?

Comment: I'm thinking there is more to this method than what you have shows us. For example, where is `cmd` defined? Can you show us the entire method?

Comment: Please update post to include your raw sql and or stored procedure. Typically you would wrap your query in a try block and catch them there and then you can return these if you want. Or there's the `SQLException` class that would give you the error's as well, but you didn't specify where you wanted these from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is an English language site. The question needs to be translated to English or moved to https://es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can catch a SQL Exception using the [SQLException class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.8). It works like this:

```
try 
{
    // your code that calls the database here
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
   // your code that handles the Sql Exception 
}
```

I typically add a double catch, just in case there is some other error in my code tht isn't SQL related:

```
try 
{
    // your code that calls the database here
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
   // your code that handles the Sql Exception 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // your code that handles normal exceptions
}
```